# How to unfix a pvc tube glued to another pvc tube?

Tags: repair, pvc

I have the following drained pvc tube pipe. As you can see from the picture below, I want to detach the part that I've circled in green (the upper part).

[image]

The pvc part has been glued.

After many readings on the internet, one of the easiest solution would be to use a heat gun/thermal cleaner to unstuck it (like in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LU9OiPLKmo)).

Is there a simpler way to unglued the pvc tube without using a heat gun?

Thank you.

Comment: use a blow torch, or jet lighter, instead of the heat gun. or you can get special drills, but heat is the cheapest method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The glue normally used is a pvc cement and « welds » the joint together.

I would cut that tee out and fit a new one with extensions to meet up with the existing pipes using couplers.

When you get the old part out, try separating a joint - they tend to « tear » the surface.

Comment: Hi @solar-mike, thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "tearing" the surface?

Comment: I have cut a glued section out and made a cut to make a "split" ring then tried to separate the two parts - the cement "welds" the surfaces together.

Comment: I agree with Mike. Cut out the old tee and just replace it.  I've tried many times in my younger years to separate  glued PVC and failed every time. Even if you can separate the pieces you'll probably damage the surface so it will leak when you reglue.

Comment: @AndyK When you make your cuts, be sure to leave enough of the remaining straight pieces (the 1 vertical and 2 horizontal) that you can slip couplings on them and glue or clamp them (with a [Fernco](https://www.fernco.com/) type clamp) together!

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, thanks. As the pipe shown in the picture is an old one, I'll go to the repair store and buy a new set. For the part that I'll saw, I'll do that from the green line (see [pic](https://gifyu.com/image/QUZ6)). It should give me enough pipe to couple the new set.

Comment: @AndyK that looks like it's in the right area. Before you start cutting, hold your couplers up to ensure that there's enough left to fully seat into the coupler. Don't forget the horizontals, as well. Especially on the right, it's starting to get really tight... You _may_ have enough flexibility with the length of pipe coming in from the left to get them all slipped together with rigid couplings, but be prepared to go to Ferncos if you don't - they're more expensive ($5-10 vs <$1 for a rigid coupler) but _sometimes_ it's the only way to get the pipes to connect

Comment: ha ha @FreeMan, infortunately I live in frogland (France), we don't have Ferncos but I'll go for something simllar.

Comment: Andy K, I think what Solar Mike is suggesting that once you have the now-throw-away joint out of the system, make an attempt to separate the parts as you might if it was in place. You'll discover true futility.

Comment: If you're interested in the details of *why* you can't separate these connections, see [this article](https://www.corzan.com/blog/why-solvent-cement-is-not-glue). Spoiler: once cemented, they become one solid piece of PVC at the molecular level.

Comment: hi @bta, brilliant. Thank you for the article, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are doing there are tools which allow you to reuse previously pvc glued couplings.

Jones Stephens Corp Socket Saver 2" Carded is one product.  Typically you wouldn't bother with the socket saver approach unless you have no access and would need to remove walls/ceilings.

Here is a decent video of the process.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQGssYM5C2M&t=1m57s

A better video with more options including using a heat gun, hole saw, socket saver and how each fares against abs and pvs:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQGHej71nWE

Another video showing how to use a heat gun to bend pvc to join in tight quarters without having to expose too much.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEUirzAbMNo

In your case I'd opt for couplings if the pipe is going to remain with the same configuration.

Comment: Hi @fresh-codemonger, I go for the coupling. It will be easier.